# How to do excel formula that would Sum values from column C if column A is 'X' or 'Y' and column B is 'Z'?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet from which I need to pick out some specific values that are in one of text columns but only if other column matches the year.

I have tried following `SUM` with `IF` but I think `OR` portion in textual column is failing...

`=SUM(IF(B:B="*Nuoma*",B:B="*(Nuomininko)*",C:C=2016,D:D))`

What I need is if in column B value contains `Nuoma` OR `(Nuomininko)` AND column C is 2016 then SUM column D...

Comment: Use sumifs() not sum(if()). Sumifs allows wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, {"*Nuoma*","*(Nuomininko)*"}, C:C, 2016))
```

The `{"*Nuoma*","*(Nuomininko)*"}` provides the OR to a wildcard match on *Nuoma* or a wildcard match containing *(Nuomininko)*. You must wrap the SUMIFS in a SUM but no CSE is required.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeeped, it doesn't seem to take `(Nuomininko)` into account, try removing it nothing changes...

Comment: If I copy B8 to B9 in my example data above, the total in G11 changes from 8 to m6.

Comment: Also If i flip vales around sum changes.... `=SUM(SUMIFS(D:D, B:B, {"*(Nuomininko)*","*Nuoma*"}, C:C, 2016))`

Comment: I would start a new sample worksheet like the one above and copy, paste and/or type the values in from the formula. There really isn't any reason this should not be working beyond a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion based on the fact that in your example, both strings 'Nuoma' and 'Nuominiko' contain the same string 'Nuom'. It uses SUMPRODUCT and SEARCH (as a substitute for wildcards) together with a help column for the string matching.

Cell D7 in the screenshot contains this formula:
`=IFERROR(SEARCH("Nuom",B7),0)`

And the summation in E15 is done by `=SUMPRODUCT(E6:E13,--(C6:C13=2016),--(D6:D13=1))`. In my example this evaluates to the sum of cells E10 and  E14: 4 + 2 = 6.

If you prefer to avoid the help column and use an array formula instead, this one produces the same result without involving column D (don't forget to do Ctrl + Shift + Enter):
`{=SUMPRODUCT(E7:E14,--(C7:C14=2016),IFERROR(SEARCH("Nuom",B7:B14),0))}`

I suppose it would be relatively straightforward to extended this to more complicated situations.

[image: SEARCH instead of wildcards with SUMPRODUCT]

Comment: For the situation with parentheses around 'Nuominiko' you can modify the formulas like this: 1) `=SUMPRODUCT(E6:E13,--(C6:C13=2016),--(D6:D13>0))` (`>0` instead of `=1`). And 2) `{=SUMPRODUCT(E7:E14,--(C7:C14=2016),IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Nuom",B7:B14)>0,1,0),0))}` (wrapping SEARCH in an IF formula).